# What would be the problem with these strange walls?

Tags: maseches-eruvin, lomdus

The [Gemara](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=3&daf=16b&format=text) discusses whether a fence made with just Shesi (horizontal component) or just Eirev (vertical component) is a wall. Some opinions say that its not.

Then there is another [Gemara](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=3&daf=19b&format=text) which discusses whether a tree with branches sticking up is considered a diomed, or whether sticks with breaks under 3 tefachim can be called a diomed.

I don't understand. In all of these cases we should say Lavud.

When do we say Lavud and when when do we not?

Answer (score 1):

We do say lovud as long as they are less than 3 tefochim.
These gemoros you mention are talking about where the distance between  them is more.

Comment: sources would greatly improve your answer

Comment: It's not always. See http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=3&daf=19b&format=text re. the Diomed